# Что за «пустая» обертка div в slick item?

Tags: javascript, html, slick.js

Что за "пустая" обертка div в slick item? На офф. сайте в примерах ее нету. В моем примере он есть. Как его убрать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
$('.js-slider').slick();
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.4-rc1/css/foundation.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.js"></script>


<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-x">
    <div class="cell medium-6 medium-offset-3">
          <div class="js-slider slider">           
            <a href="#"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=Slide 1"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=Slide 2"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=Slide 3"></a>

    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это сработает

```
$('.reviews').slick({
    draggable: false,
    infinite: true,
    rows: 0,// удаляет div  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Если это тот код который генерируется самим скриптом, то видимо эта обёртка по каким-либо причинам нужна скрипту, и если она вам не мешает, то и запариваться на эту тему не стоит.

Во многих js фрэймворках и библиотеках, например React или Vue подобные обёртки встречаются много где, и хоть возможно и был бы способ их убрать, но на это никто не запаривается, так как они обычно не мешают, просто пара лишних тэгов.

Чаще всего такие обёртки делаются как контейнер для нескольких дочерних элементов, там где система (JS библиотека или framework) по каким либо причинам не может работать без такого контейнера, либо это существенно бы усложнила её работу.

Answer (score 0):

вариант 1: из-за того что как элимент у тебя выступает ссылка с `display: inline;` - slick-slider оборачивает их в `<div>`, что-бы слайд был как блок
решение - попробуй установить этим ссылкам `display: block;` или `display: inline-block;`
вариант 2: где-то не закрыл тег, проверь html-код